# Azure policy Terraform import '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

Created Azure policy to Enforce labels on pods in Kubernetes cluster as below.

Policy Name: Enforce labels on pods in Kubernetes cluster

[image: Policy Configuration]

I am trying to import policy using below command

```
terraform import azurerm_policy_set_definition.test /subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/<Id>
```

Whenever I am trying to import resource using terraform, getting below error.

```
Error: setting `policy_definition_reference`: policy_definition_reference.0.parameters.labelsList: '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Any updates for the question? Do the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to the [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/34) in Github. I also think it looks like the parameters need to be fixed. You can see the `policy_definition_reference.0.parameters` is a mapping of the parameter values for the referenced policy rule and each member needs a string value. But the Policy Set Definition in Azure, the parameters property is an object in the JSON format like this:

[image]

Maybe it cannot convert from an object into a string in Terraform.

And I think you also need to change the format you input in the Azure portal, it should be the same as the namespace, without quotes and separated with the character `;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the ⓘ for List of labels it gives you a hint about how to submit values to the field.  You need to have labels separated with a ;.  I suspect terraform is incorrectly interpreting the values as JSON.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misspoke, this bug was fixed sooner than I thought. It was fixed in [azurerm 2.29.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v2.29.0)

*This could be because of [this bug](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8159) in the azurerm provider. A fix [is in the works](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/8270) but they mention it will likely not be released until the next major release of the azurerm provider (3.0).
I ran into this issue and had to change existing initiative definitions to have parameters at the [initiative level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/initiative-definition-structure#parameter-properties), rather than per policy inside of policy_definition_reference and have the [policy parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/initiative-definition-structure#policy-definition-properties) reference the parameters of the initiative.
Not sure if this is the best way to get around this as modifying initiative parameters [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/initiative-definition-structure#parameters) that that the initiative has no policy assignments.*